# Java/Eclipse: How Does Java/Eclipse Reserve Heap

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to diagnose a memory leak (or what I thought was a memory leak) in a real time audio program, which causes output to occasionally "stutter" when the garbage collection routine is called.

In an attempt to get back to basics and elaborate successively until I found the leak, I devised what I thought would be the simplest possible and leak-free program:

```
public class LeakDetect {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println( Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        }
    }
}
```

Imagine my surprise to find that the heap space slowly decreases over time (easily visible over the course of seconds) and then jumps back up again, even though there is no action here other than printing the available heap memory.

I have never had cause to wonder about this; what is going on here?

Does Java/Eclipse actually forcibly reserve a chunk of memory for the heap, and subsequently do something wasteful behind the scenes?

Or, as I suspect, are other programs and OS functions (Windows 10) eating into the potential heap space available, and then the OS is occasionally freeing memory?  If so, is there a way to make Java/Eclipse take a harder line about keeping the OS and other software out of its space?  Would running under Ubuntu change the answer?

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE - it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Even so, if there is a way to force the behavior I desire, I'll be going *through* Eclipse and its configuration of the JVM.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the way it works.  The JVM is boss at runtime.

Comment: Right, but I'll be setting flags, changing configuration of JVM, etc, via Eclipse.  Analogous to setting heap guidelines in eclipse.ini.  JVM is boss, but configured by IDE

Comment: You don't get it.  Once you start the job the JVM doesn't know or care how those flags were set.

Comment: So focus on the JVM part, if you know the answer:  Why is the heap changing in such a simple program?

Comment: I don't think your trivial program is a demonstration of a memory leak. Get a profiler and stop guessing about what's happening.  When I run a Java application from IntelliJ I see java.exe and idea.exe in my task manager.  You should find eclipse.exe and see what it's doing to your memory.